# Slack login in android app and get user chat notification

Tags: android, android-studio, slack, slack-api

i want to create an app where i add functionality like slack login and whenever i got a new message form any channels or individual person i got a notification in my app. i just want to use app in testing purpose

i tried testing api slack official api testing platform. but i have to give access token by myself i want that if user logged in with slack using my app access token will store and i can access users chat. Again i'm doing only for testing purpose.